# UICollectionView error: layoutAttributesForElementsInRect

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I am coding a pinterest style `UICollectionView`. It is mostly working. However, I am facing one issue - when scroll the view back and forth multiple times. The pictures suddenly overlap to on top of each other. I did some debugging and here is what I found in the `Layout class` -

**A. For the content size:**

I sum up all the size of all the cells possible and return a static value (in this case, height is 817.75..).

```
- (CGSize)collectionViewContentSize
{
    NSLog(@"content height=%f width=%f", self.contentSize.height, self.contentSize.width );
    return self.contentSize;
}
```

**B. For the following API:**

```
- (NSArray*)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

I saw when I was scrolling, rect kept changing. I noticed that my problem seems associated with one specific situation - when rect is (x=0.000000, y=568.000000) (w=301.000000, h=249.753784).

I could typically see the following values related to rect and they are all fine -

```
Rect Parameters (0.000000, 0.000000) (w=301.000000, h=817.753784)  //when moved the screen to the bottom to the top of the collection view
Rect Parameters (0.000000, 0.000000) (w=301.000000, h=568.000000)  //when move the screen to the top of the collection view
Rect Parameters (0.000000, -568.000000) (w=301.000000, h=1136.000000) //when swipe down the screen .. top of the collection view is at the middle of the screen.
```

All of them have the height equals or above the screen size (568). I am not sure how I could get the values.

> Rect Parameters (0.000000, 568.000000) (w=301.000000, h=249.753784)

Did I miss something?  Any help will be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed the same problem. Did you found a solution?